# Not able to access apache 2 from ec2 instance

Tags: apache-http-server, amazon-ec2

I installed apache 2 via this command :

`sudo apt-get install apache2`

It is successfully installed on my amazone ec2 server, but I am not able to access it from my computer.

I issued the following command :

```
$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep apache
```

and the output is as following :

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-1-1:/etc/apache2/conf-available$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep apache
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      28162/apache2
```

Please advice... What changes should I apply to make it work ?

Comment: What does the security group assigned to instance look like?

Comment: group id : sg-54008a31 & sg-96a12af3

Comment: done ! inbound rule was only SSH , added one more ALL